# How to pass the fields parameter into a google drive python API call

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have:

```
results = drive_service.files().list(**body).execute()
```

where:

```
body = {
    'q': query_string,
    'maxResults': 1,
}
```

To improve performance I would like to limit the fields returned as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/performance#partial-response

if i just add `'fields': 'id,items,title,mimeType'` to `body` i get an error. I'm not sure how to add that limitation?

Somewhat related, does the python api automatically gzip the request?

Answer (score 11):

API v2:

```
results = drive_service.files().list(fields='items(id,mimeType,title)', **body).execute()
```

you can easily figure out what the fields value should look like using API Explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list

API v3:

```
results = drive_service.files().list(fields='files(id,mimeType,name)', **body).execute()
```

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list

yes, the requests are automatically gzipped. You can turn on http traffic logging to confirm. see:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

Comment: no luck. i get: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed+%3D+false+and+title+%3D+%27Smith%2C+Mike+R.+07-21-1981%27+and+%xxxx%27+in+parents+and+mimeType+%3D+%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27&fields=items%2Ctitle%2CmimeType&alt=json&maxResults=1 returned "Invalid field selection id". it seems to have added my fields parameter into my query string just fine but doesn't accept id in the field selection. it doesn't matter what fields i list, i get a similar error.

Comment: @rsp- were you able to solve this issue. I'm getting the exact same error.No matter which field I provide, it always returns the same error.

Comment: Also, note that you can get an "Invalid field selection" error when fields do not belong to "files()". For example it's "files(id,name),nextPageToken", not "files(id,name,nextPageToken)".

Answer (score 2):

try

```
body = {
    'q': query_string,
    'maxResults': 1,
    'fields': 'items/id, items/title, items/mimeType',
}
```

or

```
body = {
    'q': query_string,
    'fields': 'items(id,title,mimeType),nextPageToken',  # if you need to get full result
}
```

Comment: Not sure why getting a down-vote, so maybe vote for delete this post is better?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, the problem was in api version.

Comment: For v2, the syntax is: `items(id,mimeType,title)` whereas it is `files(id,mimeType,name)` for the v3.

Comment: can you give the full syntax please? it doesn't help anyone when you just state items(), and files() like these.

Comment: @Liyanage try api-explorer and see what syntax it generates: [drive files v2](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive.files.list/m/drive/v2/drive.files.list), [drive files v3](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/drive.files.list/m/drive/v3/drive.files.list)

Answer (score 0):

Drive API v3 has arrived:

`https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.permissions.list?fileId=<your_file_id>&fields=permissions&_h=1&`

The field name is now `permissions`