# Missing values on resource file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

i don't understand a thing: in the [File Resource of Google reference guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) there are a lot of fields while in my Python client application there are only few key in the dictionary (id, mime-type, name, kind). I'm interested to parents list of a file given its id but i don't know how to obtain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which fields you want eg. using `fields=*` to get everything.

Comment: This is my code:                                                                                         changes = self.drive_service.changes().list(pageToken=page_token,  spaces='drive', fields='*').execute()   but return a Http error 400: bad request

Comment: Thanks for reply: by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996927/how-to-pass-the-fields-parameter-into-a-google-drive-python-api-call#13997200 i've found https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.changes.list and then i can experiment to find the right parameter to insert